# Open app using hardware buttons in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to open my ionic app using hardware buttons in phone (power button/double pressing or any other buttons) when it is closed. Or need to open the app using the tab key by pressing double times.
Any suggestion…?

Comment: Sounds like configuration of your phone's o.s. I don't think you will be able to do that from within the application